# Ionic 4 store formdata and sync on internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I have an application where I need to capture the dogs in offline mode. I have used the **formdata** because I am sending images along with the remaining data. I am using the below code to store the HTTP request.

```
storeRequest(url, type, data) {
   this.sharedService.presentToast('Your data is stored locally because you 
   seem to be offline.');

   let action: StoredRequest = {
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      time: new Date().getTime(),
      id: Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5)
   };

   return this.storage.get(STORAGE_REQ_KEY).then(storedOperations => {
      let storedObj = JSON.parse(storedOperations);

      if (storedObj) {
          storedObj.push(action);
      } else {
          storedObj = [action];
      }

      return this.storage.set(STORAGE_REQ_KEY, JSON.stringify(storedObj));
    });
 }
```

Here I am storing all the requests. When I am trying to retrieve the data, I am getting an empty object. That's why I am not able to sync the data to the server. I have used the below code to sync the requests.

```
checkForEvents(): Observable<any> {
return from(this.storage.get(STORAGE_REQ_KEY)).pipe(
  switchMap((storedOperations: any) => {
    let storedObj = JSON.parse(storedOperations);
    console.log(storedObj);
    if (storedObj && storedObj.length > 0) {
      console.log(storedObj);
      return this.sendRequests(storedObj).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.sharedService.presentToast('Local data succesfully synced to 
          API!');
          this.storage.remove(STORAGE_REQ_KEY);
        })
      );
    } else {
      console.log('no local events to sync');
      return of(false);
    }
  })
)
}
```

**Edit - **
Now my question is what is good practice to store the data?? Where can we store the formdata??

Comment: Plz check this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to window [Online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events) and perform your action eg.

```
window.addEventListener('online',  ()=>{
//save your data
});
```